# Can I suppress the text that aplay outputs when you play a .wav

Tags: audio

it puts out something like "Playing WAVE 'sounds/mailbox/mailbox-closed.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 11025 hz, Mono"
I don't need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the manual:

```
   -q --quiet
          Quiet mode. Suppress messages (not sound :))
```

So, for example:

```
aplay -q python_games/match0.wav
```

has no output.  Note, the output is to stderr, so it can be also suppressed with:

```
aplay python_games/match0.wav 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: @dogsred: "The manual" == `man aplay` https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page